# How do you get the number in nested loop?

Tags: python

When the looping completes, what number will display? Answer with a numeral. **Hint: After the outer loop has run once through one country and the inner loop has run once through four cities, outer_loop_total + inner_loop_total is 5.**

**Please explain as well on why the "Hint" results is 5 by adding the outer_loop_total + inner_loop_total = 5  ???** //Thank you!

Please explain to me how you get 14? What does outer_loop_total/inner_loop_total += 1 mean?

```
outer_loop_total = 0
inner_loop_total = 0
countries = ["Albania", "Morocco", "Brazil", "Denmark"]
capitals = ["Tel Aviv", "Abuja", "Brasília", "Islamabad"]
for country_to_check in countries:
  outer_loop_total += 1
  for city_to_check in capitals:
    inner_loop_total += 1
    if country_to_check == "Brazil" and city_to_check == "Brasília":
      print(outer_loop_total + inner_loop_total)
```

Solution: The answer is 14. That's 3 times through the outer loop to get to "Brazil"and 4 + 4 + 3 times through the inner loop to get to "Brasília"

Thank you

Comment: `x = 0; x += 1; print(x)`. You can probably make an educated guess what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs to go through 11 inner loop iterations and 3 outer loop iterations to meet the condition of the country being 'Brazil' and the capital city being 'Brasilia'.

The print statement line is only executed the once during the entire script when those conditions are met. At the point of this line being ran, 11 inner loops and 3 outer loops equals 14 in total.

The `+= 1` in code is the same as saying `outer_loop_total = outer_loop_total + 1`. It is a shorthand used for incrementing the variable.

The code `-= 1` could be used similarly as a shorthand to decrement a variable by 1.